How do you construct count measures in a cross-table in Webi Business Objects?
I'm trying to create a series of tables based on various people data, so how many staff work in Team A, Team B and so on (team info at row level) and then split further by types of worker in subsequent columns (Permanent/temporary etc). I've managed to do this using various Measure variables and all is good with the world.
The problem is when I introduce a second object at row level, so breaking the above table down even further. I'm trying to break down the number of job roles in each team and then again by type of worker (permanent, temporary etc.). I've tried a number of different variables, counts and so on, but nothing seems to be working.
There are two variables I'm struggling with that if I can get some help with, I'm confident I can use this to do everything else I need to in the table. They are:

A measure showing numbers of all staff broken down by team and role
A measure showing numbers of all staff broken down by team and role, by worker type (permanent/temporary)

For the first one, it would look like this (two columns showing what I would expect to see vs. what I am seeing):



Team
Role Type
What I expect to see
What I am seeing




Team A
Role A
55
187


Team A
Role B
4
187


Team A
Role C
48
187


Team A
Role D
80
187


Team B
Role A
288
723


Team B
Role B
236
723


Team B
Role C
42
723


Team B
Role D
157
723



So I know that I'm seeing the total of staff in each team rather than having it being broken down by job role. The measure in question is:
Count of staff by role: =Count([Staff Number]) ForEach([Team] In([Role Type])
I've tried the different combinations of ForEach, In etc but can't make it work.
For the second table, I'm even further away (this is what I expect to see):



Team
Role Type
Permanent
Temporary




Team A
Role A
40
15


Team A
Role B
3
1


Team A
Role C
40
8


Team A
Role D
65
15


Team B
Role A
200
88


Team B
Role B
210
26


Team B
Role C
30
12


Team B
Role D
140
17



And instead I'm simply getting #CONTEXT errors. The measure I'm getting the Context error for is one I've butchered from a previous successful table measure. Thought process as follows:
Permanent staff indicator: =If([Contract Type]="Permanent") Then 1 Else 0
Count of Permanent staff: =Count([Staff Number];Distinct) Where([Permanent staff indicator]=1) ForEach([Staff Number]) In([Team];[Role Type])
Same for Temporary staff but switching the variables.
Please help me!

Can you provide a sample data set?

Hi Isaac - I'm not sure how to provide a sample data set to be honest. I don't have the ability to use an external fileshare system (work computer restrictions) and can't upload anything directly. Was hoping the tables in my original comment above would suffice!

Do you have individual team member names or just Team totals? As far as sample data here is what I am getting at. Are you able to do that?

Isaac - thanks so much for your patience and getting back to me. Genuinely, I really appreciate it. I wish I had seen that link earlier in my tenure as I could have used it a few times! However, it's my 2nd to last day in my role and I can't see me being able to get this done before I leave so I don't want to waste your time further. It'll have to be for my replacement to figure out!
